# Can you factor a matrix out of a summation?

Tags: matrices, summation

Just checking, is this valid?

$\sum_{i=1}^n AV = A\sum_{i=1}^nV$

Where $A$ is a matrix, and $V$ is a vector? And more generally?

Comment: What depends on $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If $A$ is a fixed matrix which does not depend on $i$, then yes you can factor out $A$ of the summation. In the same vein, if $V$ does not depend on $i$ in any way then you can factor out $V$ although it would factor out to the right

$$\sum_{i=1}^n AV=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n A\right)V$$

In general, $AV_1+AV_2=A(V_1+V_2)$ and $A_1V+A_2V=(A_1+A_2)V$.